# jquery context menu stops working on changed info

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm having problem with the context/right-click menu. It is working how I want it to work, but the problem comes when I do it once, I'm loading file with post, that file is with the same things that the context menu needs to work, but it doesnt. When i call the **option**  action then loads the things from the post and that is it the menu context is stopping to work.

```
$("#div").contextMenu({
    menu: 'myMenu'
}, function (action, el, pos) {
    switch (action) {
    case "option":
        {
            $.post(), {}, function (info) {
                $('#div').load('url');
            });
        break;
    }
```

**Edit: From comment below: (clean up)**
I'm loading a file that contains information that I want to change. Same divs, same everything, just the info in the divs is different, and the problem is when the info is changed by the post action, then the context menu no longer appears.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Can you please clean up your question? I cannot understand it. Correct your spelling and grammar mistakes too please. If possible create an example on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: i'm loading a file that contains iformation that i want to change same divs, same everything, just the info in the divs is different, and the problem is when the info is changed by the post action, then the context menue no more appears.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the contextMenu plugin from here: 
http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

I think your menu is failing because you have invalid java script inside your anonymous function  with the switch in it.

So you your menu appears, hits the syntax error and stops everything after that.

the

```
   $.post(), {}, function (info) {
                $('#div').load('url');
            });
```

is not correctly formatted.

Comment: Yes this is the plugin but the post a gave it as an example, it is working fine. But yes after the post the menue is gone

Comment: I found why is it happening, but still searching for answer how to fix it, the problem is in the $("#div #div2").contextMene here are two divs and second is the child - div2 but i'm loading the load with only one div, and this is the right load, but with it isn't working.But when i change it like #div #div2 and load etc.. it works, but the #div2 are meny divs and it loads in to each of them the info that contains the specific url, so it isn't working properly